# Where I can download the genome sequence of various species of Fusarium?

Tags: mycology, sequence-analysis, genomes

I'm looking for genome sequence of various species of Fusarium (a kind of fungus!) on net, but I found no suitable information. Could you please help me out for this purpose? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The standard source for open-access nucleotide sequences is [GenBank](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nucleotide). Searching for [Fusarium](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=Fusarium) in GenBank gives 440421 hits, but these are shorter reads, not full genomes. Depending on your purpose, they may be useful to you.

You may also be interested in assemblies, which are collections of aligned reads stitched together, often at the scale of whole chromosomes. Assemblies with 'Fusarium' in their keywords are available [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/?term=Fusarium).

Genomes may be found [here](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/), but it does not appear that GenBank holds a complete [assembled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_assembly) genome for any Fusarium species yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are several strains of three different species of Fusarium available for download at the Broad Institute: http://www.broadinstitute.org/annotation/genome/fusarium_group/MultiHome.html

Follow the links to Download on the sidebar.